# Notification Text is not visible in notification bar in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM push notification in my app . But I am not getting text message and icon. It only shows white background.

This is our code for receiving notification in my app

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    //Getting the message from the bundle
    String message = data.getString("message");
    //Displaying a notiffication with the message
    String body = null;
    String title = null;
    try{
        String notificationJSONString = data.getString("notification");
        //then you can parse the notificationJSONString into a JSON object
        JSONObject notificationJSON = new JSONObject(notificationJSONString );
        body = notificationJSON.getString("body");
        title = notificationJSON.getString("title");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // sendNotification(message);
    sendNotification(body,title);
}

//This method is generating a notification and displaying the notification
private void sendNotification(String message,String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("firsttab","notify");
    int requestCode = 0;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    // .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.philips_launcher)
        .setSmallIcon( getNotificationIcon())
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(sound)
        .setColor(Color.parseColor("#0089C4"))
        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
        // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
      /*  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
        } else {
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        }*/

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noBuilder.build()); //0 = ID of notification
}

private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.not_icon : R.mipmap.philips_launcher;
}
```

Comment: what is your GCM post request?

Comment: we get data in on messageReceive function like this

Comment: Bundle[{notification=Bundle[{sound2=1, e=1, body=heyyy, icon=, badge=1, 
sound=default, title=Philips CORTA-NEW Notification, vibrate=1}], collapse_key=com.philips.ordertracker}]

Comment: I dont believe the content of the push message is JSON

Answer (score 0):

In message string you are getting the notification no need to parse it further
 String message = data.getString("message");
and you can give the title by your on the base your app if there is no title coming along with that message

Answer (score 0):

Change this code and try it i hope it's work fine.
You have missing `.Build();` at last.

From:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           // .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.philips_launcher)
            .setSmallIcon( getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#0089C4"))
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
           // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

To:

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder noBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           // .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.philips_launcher)
            .setSmallIcon( getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#0089C4"))
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
           // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .. let me check and back to you

Comment: I guess the OP never checked the answer

Answer (score 0):

The white background issue with notification messages is known and is being fixed, the fix should be released soon. Another option is to use data messages and manage the creation of the notification yourself in the onMessageReceived callback.